# Swift 2 - Regex validate User Name

Tags: regex, string, swift2

I am trying to validate a user name using a Regex in swift. I found the way to match the string if there are any not world or digit character however, I need to find the way to add in the regex an expression that tells me that the string length is between a range of `2...15` characters.

How can I do this?

```
let name = Anthony 
if let match = name.rangeOfString("[\\W]|[\\d]{2,15}$", options: .RegularExpressionSearch) {
    print(match)
}
```

Comment: thanks! This works only with digits

Comment: Try `"^(?:[\\p{L}\\p{M}]|\\d){2,15}$"`. Note that `\p{L}` matches a Unicode letter, and `\p{M}` matches diacritics. `\d` will match a digit. When we place all of them into a character class, we match either a (precomposed) letter or a digit, 2 to 15 times.

Comment: Thanks #stribizhev, this works however, how can I do the opposite? The expression need to match if the string is <2 and >15 ----- `!{2,15}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `^(?:[\\p{L}\\p{M}]|\\d){2,15}$` to match any string that has 2 to 15 characters that are either letters or digits.

Note that `\p{L}` matches a Unicode letter, and `\p{M}` matches diacritics. `\d` will match a digit. When we place all of them into a character class, we match either a (precomposed) letter or a digit, 2 to 15 times.

> The expression need to match if the string is <2 and >15 ----- !{2,15}

You can use `"^(?:[\\p{L}\\p{M}]|\\d)$|^(?:[\\p{L}\\p{M}]|\\d){16,}$"`:

```
let name = "n"
let valid_block = "(?:[\\p{L}\\p{M}]|\\d)"
if let match = name.rangeOfString("^" + valid_block + "$|^" + valid_block + "{16,}$", options: .RegularExpressionSearch) {
    print(match)
}
```

See the [SWIFT code demo](http://swiftstub.com/470176487)

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you.